# how to set ms-access combo box selected index

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

In my MS Access project I need to set selected index of a **combobox** using VBA. I used the syntax below to select the first item.

```
Application.CommandBars("MainMenu").Controls("Country").SelectedValue = "US"
```

After use the above syntax I get the error ”Object does not support this property or method”

[image]

I need help to setting the combo box selected item

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 Me.fromDate = Me.fromDate.ItemData(0)    'Get first item and set that to the selected value
    
 Me.toDate = Me.toDate.ItemData(Me.toDate.ListCount - 1) 'Get last item and set that to the selected value
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the desired selected value directly:

```
Me!cboTest = "US"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Access 2013 ListIndex is readonly.  You can change the value of the combobox as suggested above.  When you do so, the ListIndex is modified by Access but it won't point to the row you used.  I've not found any information on how to select a row and have the ListIndex point to that row after selection.  The only solution I can come up with is to keep static variables around that I maintain to keep track of what is really selected.

Comment: This would be more useful on a similar question that did not have the [tag:access-2007] tag, since this appears to apply only to later versions.

Comment: I think these sorts of updates that reflect the new reality are welcome, especially since this was tagged with ms-access tag, too. There's nothing worse than trying a fix only to find it doesn't work with newer versions These sorts of clarifications are very useful.

Comment: I just successfully set the ListIndex property on a ComboBox in Access 2013 (after first calling SetFocus on the control... otherwise error 7777).  The online docs indicate Read/Write:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845909.aspx

Comment: @CPerkins The `.Listindex` property is read-only according to the link you cited (as of this comment date).  In the past 20 years I don't know of a time when it was ever read-write but I'd love if you could prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hope Bellow syntax solve problem

Just use the combo.ListIndex=ComboBoxIndex

Comment: This won't work.  The `.ListIndex` property of a combo box is [read-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.listindex?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaac10.chm11444)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue).